# Pytest Fixtures - Parameterisation - Call Fixture Once

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a fixture that returns the endpoint for the name of that endpoint (passed in)

The name is a string set in the test. I have messed up by calling the endpoint each time in the tests (parameterised) and now I can't figure out how to get the same functionality working without calling the endpoint each time.

Basically I just need to call the endpoint once and then pass that data between all my tests in that file (Ideally without anything like creating a class and calling it in the test. I have about 12 files each with similar tests and I want to reduce the boiler plate. Ideally if it could be done at the fixture/parametrisation level with no globals.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('field', [('beskrivelse'), ('systemId')])
def test_intgra_001_elevforhold_req_fields(return_endpoint, field):
    ep_to_get = 'get_elevforhold'
    ep_returned = return_endpoint(ep_to_get)
    apiv2 = Apiv2()
    apiv2.entity_check(ep_returned, field, ep_to_get, False)


@pytest.fixture()
def return_endpoint():

    def endpoint_initialisation(ep_name):
        apiv2 = Apiv2()
        ep_data = apiv2.get_ep_name(ep_name)
        response = apiv2.get_endpoint_local(ep_data, 200)
        content = json.loads(response.content)
        apiv2.content_filt(content)
        apiv2_data = content['data']

        return apiv2_data

    return endpoint_initialisation
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `return_endpoint` as a fixture with scope `session` and store data in a dictionary after it is fetched. The fixture doesn't return the initialization function, but a function to access the dictionary.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('field', [('beskrivelse'), ('systemId')])
def test_intgra_001_elevforhold_req_fields(return_endpoint, field):
    ep_to_get = 'get_elevforhold'
    ep_returned = return_endpoint(ep_to_get)
    apiv2 = Apiv2()
    apiv2.entity_check(ep_returned, field, ep_to_get, False)


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def return_endpoint():
    def endpoint_initialisation(ep_name):
        apiv2 = Apiv2()
        ep_data = apiv2.get_ep_name(ep_name)
        response = apiv2.get_endpoint_local(ep_data, 200)
        content = json.loads(response.content)
        apiv2.content_filt(content)
        apiv2_data = content['data']

        return apiv2_data

    ep_data = dict()
    def access(ep_name):
        try:
            return ep_data[ep_name]  # or use copy.deepcopy
        except KeyError:
            ep_data[ep_name] = endpoint_initialisation(ep_name)
            return ep_data[ep_name]  # or use copy.deepcopy

    return access
```

There are some caveats here. If the object returned by `endpoint_initialisation()` is mutable, then you potentially create unwanted dependencies between your tests. You can avoid this by returning a (deep) copy of the object. You can use the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html) for that.